# Why does the slideshow skip the last slide?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I built a slideshow using JavaScript, CSS, and HTML. The code skips the last slide and I don't understand why. So, if anyone can enlighten why it does this that would be great.

I've tried changing things in JavaScript like adding to slideshow or taking away the -1 knowing I need it but nothing works and I'm stumped.

```js
window.onload = function() { // add window.onload here and set it euqal to a function
  var timeOut;
  var slideIndex = 0;
  var slides;
  showSlides(slideIndex);
  // Next/previous controls
  window.plusSlides = function(n) {
    showSlides(n);
  }
  // Thumbnail image controls
  window.currentSlide = function(n) {
    slideIndex = (n - 1)
    showSlides();
  }

  function bind() {
    clearInterval(timeOut)
    timeOut = setInterval(showSlides, 5000);
  }

  function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    if (n)
      slideIndex += n;
    else slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex >= slides.length || slideIndex < 1) {
      slideIndex = 1
    }

    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
    bind();
  }

}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Hide the images by default */

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: -15px;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through 
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
*/


/* Caption text */

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e1/Nuernberg-fronfeste-und-kettensteg-v-O.jpg" style="width:1000px; height: 540px;">
    <div class="text"><span style="background-color: black">one on one weekly siminars</span></div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e1/Nuernberg-fronfeste-und-kettensteg-v-O.jpg" style="width:1000px; height: 540px;">
    <div class="text"><span style="background-color: black">monthly seminars/workshops</span></div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e1/Nuernberg-fronfeste-und-kettensteg-v-O.jpg" style="width:1000px; height: 540px;">
    <div class="text"><span style="background-color: black">nursing home visits</span></div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e1/Nuernberg-fronfeste-und-kettensteg-v-O.jpg" style="width:1000px; height: 540px;">
    <div class="text"><span style="background-color: black">community service</span></div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e1/Nuernberg-fronfeste-und-kettensteg-v-O.jpg" style="width:1000px; height: 540px;">
    <div class="text"><span style="background-color: black">college visits</span></div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e1/Nuernberg-fronfeste-und-kettensteg-v-O.jpg" style="width:1000px; height: 540px;">
    <div class="text"><span style="background-color: black">Annual Summer Retreat</span></div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="pictures%20updated/12.jpg" style="width:1000px; height: 540px;">
    <div class="text"><span style="background-color: black">Annual Horse Camp</span></div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e1/Nuernberg-fronfeste-und-kettensteg-v-O.jpg" style="width:1000px; height: 540px;">
    <div class="text"><span style="background-color: black">Annual Horse Camp</span></div>
  </div>


  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>



<!-- The dots/circles -->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="curretnslide(4)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentslide(5)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentslide(6)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentslide(7)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentslide(8)"></span>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Maybe this is why: "if (slideIndex >= slides.length || slideIndex < 1) { slideIndex = 1 }"  ... you then go on to use slideIndex - 1 as the array index, so the last one would never be achievable. I'm not able to test this suggestion so I won't post it as an answer yet.

Comment: slideIndex = (n -1) , wont this mean that you will never get to your last slide?

Comment: Your suggestion is right, @Romen -- I have tested it to confirm. Note, Thanatos Raven, you have numerous typos in your dots/circles section so your navigation does not work as expected.

Comment: Yeah, as Romen was pointing at you want to take out the = part and change it to `if (slideIndex > slides.length || slideIndex < 1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `showSlides()` checks to see if `slideIndex` is greater than *or equal to* the length of your slideshow. Then you access your slide element using `slideIndex - 1`. In the case where `slideIndex == slides.length` you are resetting to 1 even though you account for this offset of 1 (counting from 1) inside the array brackets.

The corrected if statement below should work:

```javascript
if (slideIndex > slides.length || slideIndex < 1) {
    slideIndex = 1
}
```

I suggest that you avoid performing arithmetic inside array brackets. When you do this it undermines the meaning of the name "slideIndex" because it is not truly the slide index you are using.